# How to query single value in Firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I loop through a list of users client side, and for ever one, I do a firebase query to check if each one is online. The data looks like this:

```
  "users" : {
   "EptMK62Kt1Sp1EIb5meuKHVpUqs1" : {
    "isConnected" : true,
    "isGuestUser" : true,
    "lastOnline" : 1513716962997,
    "profilePicture" : "5a36e6c355f325227859",
    "username" : "oioioioi"
    }
}
```

I want to only return the data of that user if isConnected is true. Currently I can only seem to use the highest level tree containing all the users, then queryOrdered by child, but that assumes I don't know the user IDs. It is an odd situation, but this does not work:

```
Database.database().reference().child(userID).child("isConnected").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)
```

nor does any alternative I can think of!

Comment: What is this line of code returning? Isn't this already filtering out the values?

Comment: it returns null

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Also please expand the JSON to include a bit more context around the userId node.

Comment: ok, changed it now

Comment: anyone? Are u saying it's not possible to do this simple thing using firebase?